# How does gridDB ensures that 100% of the data is persisted?

Tags: griddb

How does gridDB ensures that 100% of the data is persisted on storage as it follows memory first and storage second approach? or is it susceptible to data loss in case of sudden shutdowns?

The gridDB documentation is not very clear on it or may be I didn’t find anything related.